# How do I remove items from my to be output dictionary in python?

Tags: python, spyder

I need to create a function where in my final output:

```
[{'open': [{'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 0}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 1}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 2}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 3}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 4}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 5}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2100', 'day': 6}], 'hours_type': 'REGULAR', 'is_open_now': False}]
```

I do not want 'is_overnight' and the key. How do i do it?

Tried this:

```
def is_clocked(business_id):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    try:
        clocked_ind = get_business(API_KEY, business_id)
        clocked_ind1 = clocked_ind['hours']
    except:
        clocked_ind1 = 'None'
    return clocked_ind1
clocked_ind = is_clocked(b_id)
print(clocked_ind)
#testing
hours = clocked_ind #.pop("is_overnight")
hours.pop('is_overnight')
print(hours)
```

did not work!

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the `list` and delete `is_overnight` key and its value of every `dict`. Like:

```
my_list = [{'open': [{'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 0},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 1},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 2},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 3},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 4},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 5},
           {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2100', 'day': 6}], 'hours_type': 'REGULAR',
  'is_open_now': False}]

for i in my_list[0]["open"]:
    del i["is_overnight"]

print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'open': [{'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 0}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 1}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 2}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 3}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 4}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 5}, {'start': '1100', 'end': '2100', 'day': 6}], 'hours_type': 'REGULAR', 'is_open_now': False}]
```

Comment: Thank you Taohidul. I want to get the output in a data frame and export it to excel where I will be able to see it as "start1,start0" and "end1, end0". how would i go about it?

Comment: That's another question. If you get answer of this question then please accept the best answer and ask another one.